# Outlook marking new inbox messages as read when viewing another folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a similar issue to this: [Outlook automatically marks message as read before it is viewed](https://superuser.com/questions/41416/outlook-automatically-marks-message-as-read-before-it-is-viewed)

Except that email arriving in my empty inbox is marked as read after 2 seconds even when the reading pane is displaying an existing email in another folder, or the reading pane is not visible (e.g. Outlook Today is showing). I've disabled all rules, and narrowed it down to the "mark as read after n seconds" setting (if I set it to 10 seconds, it takes 10 seconds to be marked as read, if I disable it, the emails are not marked as read).

Is this a bug or expected behaviour? Could it be that an update patch broke it? 
This behaviour seems to have started in the last few months as I've always had my reading pane  set to mark mail as read after 2 seconds and never remember having had a problem with this before. I might be mistaken on that of course...

Using Office Professional Plus 2010 64-bit (14.0.7116.5000) on Windows 7, with all available Microsoft Update patches applied.

Comment: OK, when I said I had all the latest patches that was based on checking before 5pm BST yesterday... I just got prompted to install today's Windows Updates, including [KB2881028][1], which is the only one that doesn't say what it fixes, just "This update provides the latest fixes for Office 2010. It also includes stability and performance improvements."

Now the problem seems to have stopped. Hurrah.


  [1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2881028